# Section and subsection name in headings

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr, sections-paragraphs

I'd like to make the headings of my article look like this:

```
<Section name>                        <Subsection number> <Subsection name> | <Page number>
```

and I wrote this code:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}

\lhead{\fancyplain{} {\sectionmark}}
\rhead{\fancyplain{} {\subsectionmark} $|$ \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth} {0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth} {0pt}
```

But it just doesn't show the names of sections and subsections.

This is what I get:

```
                                                                            | 2
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you use `twoside` mode? Do you use the `article` document class? Do you use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)? Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For capturing the section unit titles and have [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr)-style headings, Javier Bezos' [`titleps` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps) provides an easy alternative:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{main}{%
  \setheadrule{0pt}%
  \sethead{\sectiontitle}                                 % header left
    {}                                                    % header center
    {\thesubsection~\subsectiontitle\quad$|$\quad\thepage}% header right
}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[5-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\section{Another section}\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[3-4]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[5-6]
\subsection{A subsection}\lipsum[7-8]
\subsection{Another subsection}\lipsum[9-10]
\end{document}
```

Within `twoside` mode, you could use

```
\sethead[<even-left>][<even-center>][<even-right>]
  {<odd-left>}{hodd-center>}{<odd-right>}
\setfoot[<even-left>][<even-center>][<even-right>]
  {<odd-left>}{<odd-center>}{<odd-right>}
```

for setting different headers/footers on even/odd pages.

You have to decide which `\subsection` to include in your headers. `titleps` uses the last-defined sectional heading. However, see the [`titleps` documentation](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/archive/titleps.pdf) for more options (section **4. Marks**, p 4 onwards).

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks very much, Werner. Your example is wonderful, too